# Connection string for MySQL missing in other projects

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, wpf, entity-framework

I am currently developing a solution with both an ASP.NET project, and a WPF application. I have a common project too, with an ADO.NET entity model, where entities are generated from a database.

If i try to call anything from my database (MySQL) from my WPF, ASP or a Test project i get a InvalidOperationException where it says that no connection string named "DataModel" could be found in application config file.

I then have to add entity framework connectionstrings and other stuff to each project, in order to be able to fetch data from my common project or database. It also means if i want to change the db connection i have to do it in every single project. Isn't there a smarter way to do this?

Thanks..

Comment: The main advantage of keeping connectionstring into your config file in my opinion, is being able to use your entities project with different database users for different projects. While some projects should only really have reading permissions, you might write some tools for yourself which have to have write/delete permissions too. Then you can put another connectionstring in that project with the login details for your database admin user.

Answer (score 1):

`Isn't there a smarter way to do this` You're doing what most people do, at least for small and medium environments, by putting the connection string in each project.

Most projects need different connection strings for different environments (DEV, QA, PRODUCTION). I use and highly recommend the free add-in [Slow Cheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5). That tool allows you to define XSLT transforms to modify XML files in your project. In this case, I use it to drop in the correct connection string depending on the build settings.

When you are ready to create a build for the PRODUCTION environment, you just change the Visual Studio solution configuration to Release, and the generated web.config/app.config contains the PRODUCTION connection string.

Comment: Interesting plugin, going to check it out myself. This should be awesome for configuring loggers etc. too :)

Comment: Yep I also use it for NLog configuration files.

Comment: So having multiple connection string is just the way it should be?

Comment: One connection string configuration per project is common. If each project is connecting to the same database, you would find the same connection string details in each web.config/app.config.

Comment: Thanks. I know where to find the connection strings in each project, and they connect to the same database. I just think it is wierd that one connection string isn't enough :) The problem is when i want to change the database, i have to change in every project. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: If you find yourself changing the connection strings often, you can certainly create a mechanism to update all of your .config files from a central place (or do a global search/replace in Visual Studio). I don't tend to have that issue in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the connectionstring that has to be used to the constructor of your DbContext. You have 3 options to pass a connectionstring:

1. Pass nothing, EF will look for defaultconnectionstring in configfile, if none is found it will throw an error.
2. Pass the name of the connectionstring you want to use, if it's not found in the config file EF will use the default connectionstring.

   ```
   public partial class MyDb : DbContext
   {
       public MyDb(string connectionStringName) : base(connectionStringName)
   }
   ```
3. Pas a connectionstring to the constructor. EF won't look in any config files and just use that one, this is probably what you're looking for:

   ```
   public partial class MyDb : DbContext
   {
       public MyDb(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)

       //Or hardcode it in:

       public MyDb() : base("datasource=...")
   }
   ```

**Edit:** It is indeed not good practice to do the above, I'm just saying it's possible.

Comment: Default connection strings and hard-coded connection strings both invite problems in anything but a trivial environment.

Comment: @EricJ. I know but he asks if it's possible and I say how it's possible.

Comment: You're not wrong, I'm just cautioning that those two choices may not be wise :-)

Comment: Thanks :) Will try this, but i can see the problem. Isn't it possible to just use the same app.config file, since i also use the same providers and other stuff. There is a lot of redundant work in my situation, because every project uses it own app.config file, but i just want every project to use the things implemented in the common app.config..

Comment: Nope, the config file that's used is the config file of the executing assembly. The only way to be able to define a connectionstring in your class library itself is to hardcode it in (or keep it in an embedded resource or something). It won't hurt for small projects anyways, you could always change it later on after all.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderDerck! :) Would you say it is best practice to have connection strings in each config file in medium/small project?

Comment: That's what I always do myself yes. Only time I hardcode strings is for some little test entity projects. Imagine you use your entity project in 5 different applications and suddenly in one of them you need to use another connectionstring. That would require that you change the code of those 5 projects instead vs just changing one config file. Overloading the `DbContext` constructor is also an option of course.

Comment: Thanks! I will continue the way i am doing :)